# Jmeter CSV data config | pass particular valus from the csv sheet

Tags: function, csv, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

In JMeter, if there’s any function to pass particular values from the CSV datasheet.

In the CSV datasheet first column gives the mobile number and I call the values using parameterization.

${mobile number}

In my CSV datasheet first column gives the mobile number and I pass the values on my request using the parameterization. if there are any functions available to trim the value.

Ex: in CSV datasheet first column value is +911234567890

When I pass the values in the request without a country code.

${mobile number} == 1234567890

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all your entries in the CSV use [India country code of `+91`](https://countrycode.org/india) you can use [__groovy() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) like:

```
${__groovy(vars.get('your-variable-from-csv').substring(3),)}
```

[image]

Replace the `your-variable-from-csv` with the real [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) name from the [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)